# Ordenar archivo txt en PHP

Tags: php

estimados todos.

Tengo un código sencillo en PHP que ingresa datos de un formulario y luego lo guarda en un archivo ".txt", el problema es que los datos quedan juntos, y necesito aprender la forma correcta en que queden un poco mas organizados, por ejemplo:

Nombre: Pepe
Apellido: Castillo
Email: Pepe_Castillo@Email.com
Edad: 57

Este es el codigo que emplee:

[image: Code PHP]

Comment: Una opción podría ser guardar los datos en un archivo csv, de esta manera la información te quedaría organizada por columnas, pero depende del objetivo que tengas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fwrite()` escribe el contenido de un `string` al archivo apuntado por `$handle`.

El `string` es simplemente la cadena que va a ser escrita. Por lo que pueden concatenar normalmente.

```
fwrite($handle, "Esta es la cadena inicial: " . $miVariable . PHP_EOL . "Con este último PHP_EOL tendrias un salto de línea.")
```

La salida sería algo como:

```
Esta es la cadena inicial: miVariable
Con este último PHP_EOL tendrías un salto de línea.
```

---

Además puedo recomendar que el string lo crees antes, para meterlo más comodamente.

```
$string = "Este sería el string completo, creo que no da problemas agregar los saltos de línea además.";
fwrite($handle, $string);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, solvente el problema.
Soy muy novato en esto aún :'c

Lo organicé de este modo:
fwrite($file,'Nombre:'.$nombre. PHP_EOL .'Apellido:'.$apellidofwrite. etc...

Comment: Tranquilo, es cosa de practica. Como te dije es solo una concatenacion y ya.